# How can you mock a method that returns an interface?

Tags: c#, moq

I need to mock a method that returns an interface and I can't figure it out. This was my try. I don't know how what to return, as you can not return an interface.

```
        messagingClient.Setup(x =>
             x.CreateMessage(new OrganizationUserDeletedDomainEvent
             {
                 UserType = 1,
                 OrganizationUserId = 1,
                 OrganizationId = 1,
                 DeletedAt = 100000
             })).Returns();
```

The method has this signature:

```
IMessage<TContent> CreateMessage<TContent>(TContent messageContent)
   where TContent : class, new();
```

Comment: Mock a type that implements the interface and return an instance of that?

Comment: Can you show the subject under test that this mock is to be exercised against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a mock of `IMessage` and use this mock to be returned

```
var messageMock = new Mock<IMessage<OrganizationUserDeletedDomainEvent>>();

messagingClient.Setup(x =>
     x.CreateMessage(new OrganizationUserDeletedDomainEvent
     {
         UserType = 1,
         OrganizationUserId = 1,
         OrganizationId = 1,
         DeletedAt = 100000
     })).Returns(messageMock.Object);
```

Comment: I suggest advising them about using an argument matcher instead of  the instance in the setup as they will encounter problems getting the desired behavior